# ValueError: Converting String of addition/multiplication to int

Tags: python, dataset

I have a string (`add = ["25 + 1"]`) and I want to convert this string to type integer so that I can get the output as 26. I don't know how to achieve this in one go. If someone can please assist with a solution without splitting them. Is there some way in python to handle such cases.

```
import re
df="Please solve 25 + 1"
add = re.search(r'\d{1,5} (?:\+|-) \d{1,5}',df)
print(int((add[0])))
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '25 + 1'

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Please solve 25 + 1"
nums= [int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]
result = 0
print (sum(nums))
```

result:

26

addition of positive or negative numbers:

```
import re
str = "Please solve 25 + (-1)" # or str = "Please solve 25 + -1"
nums=[int(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', str)]
print (sum(nums))
```

result:

24

Comment: Clever, but this will only work for addition of positive numbers. Also you could just write `result = sum(nums)`. Anyway, the question is closed now.

Comment: definitely I agree with : sum(nums) (I just edited my post) . 
I gave solution for example ,I didn't expect negative numbers, he didn't mention it in his post @AlexHall

Comment: I just changed the post and added a code that works with negative and positive numbers @AlexHall

Comment: Again, the question is closed, so this is really just for your own interest, but I was saying initially that it only works for *addition* of positive numbers. OP's title mentions multiplication and his code sample contains subtraction. This will not work for `25 - 1`.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but this is just a response to the posted post, he did not mention other mathematical operations like subtraction(as you note : 25 - 1), maybe multiplication, and so on...

Comment: I just told you where multiplication and subtraction were mentioned...